# In a Query Engine when is it possible to push down aggregation before join?

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions

I want to write a job to join and aggregate data coming from two different services. The problem is that one of the sources is only capable of giving out aggregated data.

So if I wanted to calculate this -

```
SELECT SUM(a.a), SUM(x.x)
FROM a INNER JOIN
     x
     ON a.k=x.k
group by a.b, a.k, x.y;
```

I do -

```
Table a' = SELECT SUM(a.a) as a1, a.k as k1 FROM a GROUP BY a.k,a.b;
Table x' = SELECT SUM(x.x) as x1,  x.k as k1 FROM x GROUP BY x.y, x.k;
```

Finally,

```
SELECT SUM(a'.a1), SUM(x'.x1)
FROM a' INNER JOIN
     x'
     ON a'.k1=x'.k1
GROUP BY a'.k1;
```

I understand that this will yield inaccurate results. But it looks like it does work in some cases, for example when both the data sources are grouped by only the join key.

I want to know under what all cases will this yield accurate result?

Comment: This should work for any associative aggregate, but will fail for any aggregate that does not hold this property. Grouping on the join key is just about the only way unless you want to be sneaky and return an "aggregate" by applying a maximum on all non-key fields and grouping by the primary key.

Comment: We are dealing with huge datasets. Grouping by the Primary key will completely blow up memory.

Comment: I assume you mean the client's memory, because server-side the group would just be paged to disk. Anyway, as I mentioned, associative aggregates will work just fine.